# File delete rights in Linux

Tags: linux, access-rights

I have the following problem, I run a script on multiple servers that writes files on a single server.
Files are written with these rights:
`-rw-r--r-- 1 someuser someuser  139 Apr  2 12:40 filename.jpg`
What I would like to do would be to be able to delete this file via a php script that runs with *www-data* rights.
Is there a way to configure something so *www-data* is allowed to remove the above file?

Answer (score 1):

The php script run wiht user (*euid*): *www-data* and group (*egid*): *www-data*.
One solution may be the following:

> -rw-rw-r-- 1 someuser www-data 139 Apr 2 12:40 filename.jpg

In this situation, the php script could delete the file without problems.

Comment: Thanks but this would require to change the files so that the generated files have different rights and that was something I tried to avoid :) It looks like I'd have to do it this way though.